# Java Output Malfunction

Tags: java

I created a problem with the goal to produce a pay stub. This program will not generate any regular pay output, instead just saying "$0.00". Can't figure out the problem.

> Expected:  "Regular Hours: 40       Reg Rate: $15.50    Reg Pay:
>   $620.00  "
>   My code: "Regular Hours: 40       Reg Rate: $15.50    Reg
>   Pay: $0.00    "

I've attempted to reformat it but I am still getting this error.

```
public class Activity2PayStub {

    public static final double OVERTIME_FACTOR = 1.5;
    public static final double FEDERAL_FACTOR = 0.2;
    public static final double SOCIAL_FACTOR = 0.1;

    private String employeeName;
    private String employeeSSN;
    private int regularH;
    private int overtimeH; 
    private double payrateH; 
    private double regularPay = (regularH * payrateH);
    private double overtimePR = payrateH * (OVERTIME_FACTOR);
    private double overtimePay = overtimePR * overtimeH;
    private double grossPay = regularPay + overtimePay; 
    private double ssTax = grossPay * (SOCIAL_FACTOR);
    private double federalTax = (grossPay - ssTax) * (FEDERAL_FACTOR);
    private double netPay = grossPay - (federalTax + ssTax);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        Activity2PayStub a2ps = new Activity2PayStub();

        a2ps.getInput(keyboard);
        a2ps.calculate();
        a2ps.printPayStub();
    }

    /** @param keyboard command-line arguments. */ 
    public void getInput(Scanner keyboard) {
        System.out.print("Enter employee name: ");
        employeeName = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter employee SNN (incl. hyphens: ");
        employeeSSN = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter number of regular hours worked: ");
        regularH = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter number of overtime hours worked: ");
        overtimeH = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter hourly pay rate : ");
        payrateH = keyboard.nextDouble();  
    }

    public void calculate() {
    }

    /** simply prints. */
    public void printPayStub() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("_______________________"
            + "_____________________________________________");

        String format = "Name: %-37s SSN: %-11s\n";
        System.out.printf(format, employeeName, employeeSSN);

        format = "Regular Hours: %-8d Reg Rate: $%-8.2f Reg Pay: $%-8.2f\n";
        System.out.printf(format, regularH, payrateH, regularPay);

        format = "Overtime Hours: %-8dOT Rate: $%-8.2f  OT Pay: $%-8.2f\n";
        System.out.printf(format, overtimeH, overtimePR, overtimePay);

        format = "Gross Pay: $%-8.2f\n";
        System.out.printf(format, grossPay);

        format = "SS Withholding: $%-8.2f\n";
        System.out.printf(format, ssTax);

        format = "Federal Tax: $%-8.2f\n";
        System.out.printf(format, federalTax);

        format = "Net Pay: $%-8.2f\n";
        System.out.printf(format, netPay);

        System.out.println("________________________"
        + "__________________________________________");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

That is because the calculations are performed at instance creation. You should move the calculations to the `calculate()` method.

The [JLS chapter 8.3.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.2) confirms this:

> If the declarator is for an instance variable (that is, a field that is not static), then the variable initializer is evaluated and the assignment performed each time an instance of the class is created

Comment: Thank u! I tried that out and I am still receiving the same error.

Comment: @Lynn Then you need to update your question to show us how exactly you implemented it.

Comment: What you just did is declaring local variables with the same name as the instance variables. You need to refer to the instance variables. If you delete the data type part of the statements, it'll work. I suggest you to read up on [classes and objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html), as you seem to miss some of the basics.